# Shortest duplicate in a list of strings

Tags: python

imagine I got a list of strings containing duplicates with different lengths:

```py
liste = ['I am googling for the solution for an hour now',
         'I am googling for the solution for an hour now --Sent via mail--',
         'I am googling for the solution for an hour now --Sent via mail-- What are you doing?',
         'Hello I am good thanks >> How are you?',
         'Hello I am good thanks',
         'Hello I am good thanks >>']
```

Wanted Output:

```py
liste = ['I am googling for the solution for an hour now', 'Hello I am good thanks']
```

As you can see the strings are pretty close to duplicates but aren't exact duplicates. So a approach like this doesn't work:

```
mylist = list(dict.fromkeys(liste))
```

Have you got any idea how to just keep the shortest duplicate? The duplicates are always consecutive.

EDIT:

The order of the input list shouldn't be disturbed.

Comment: Do you want to keep just the shortest sentence?

Comment: Yeah! I mean shortest but have written least longest...sorry

Comment: What is the genral logic behind the *"pretty closeness"* of your so called duplicates? They all start with one other?

Comment: If you had a minimum length that you wanted to consider, you could probably figure something out with regular expressions, but you need enough that `hi, how are you today?` and `hello I am good thanks` don't just return `h`. Otherwise, if you want something more complex, you're getting into natural language processing.

Comment: user2390182 yeah! the duplicates themselves always start with one another. There are just some longer and I want to keep the shortest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
mylist = []
for s in sorted(liste):
    if not (mylist and s.startswith(mylist[-1])):
        mylist.append(s)
```

You can then recover the original order of occurence:

```
mylist[:] = filter(set(mylist).__contains__, liste)
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'startwith'

Comment: Yeah, already fixed that. Must be `startswith`

Comment: Is there also a way to do that with out disturbing the order of the original list?

Comment: @soulwreckedyouth I added a simple step to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so despite my suggestion in the comments to use regular expressions, I chose to try something that doesn't. Instead, I made a numpy array that tracks the similarity of strings and uses that to come up with similar strings. It's a bit klunky and the main algorithm in the nested for loop could probably be cleaned up a bit to optimize performance, but it seems to work.

I use a default when comparing an string to itself of `0.9` instead of 1 to make sure things didn't always default to themselves, but I didn't really explore if this is necessary.

```
import numpy as np

mylist = ['I am googling for the solution for an hour now',
          'I am googling for the solution for an hour now --Sent via mail--',
          'I am googling for the solution for an hour now --Sent via mail-- What are you doing?',
          'Hello I am good thanks >> How are you?',
          'Hello I am good thanks',
          'Hello I am good thanks >>']

N = len(mylist)

overlap = np.ones((N,N))

for i in range(N):
   for j in range(N):
      if i == j: overlap[i,j] = 0.9
      else:
         x = min(len(mylist[i]), len(mylist[j]))
         for k in range(x):
            if mylist[i][k] != mylist[j][k]: break
         overlap[i,j] = (k+1) / len(mylist[i])

newlist = []
for i in range(N):
   j = np.argmax(overlap[:,i])
   print(f"{mylist[i]} --> {mylist[j]}")
   newlist.append(mylist[j])
#I am googling for the solution for an hour now --> I am googling for the solution for an hour now
#I am googling for the solution for an hour now --Sent via mail-- --> I am googling for the solution for an hour now
#I am googling for the solution for an hour now --Sent via mail-- What are you doing? --> I am googling for the solution for an hour now
#Hello I am good thanks >> How are you? --> Hello I am good thanks
#Hello I am good thanks --> Hello I am good thanks
#Hello I am good thanks >> --> Hello I am good thanks
```

Then your new set is:

```
print(list(set(newlist)))
#['Hello I am good thanks', 'I am googling for the solution for an hour now']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort your list by length, then loop through each element to see if the others (longer strings) start with it.

```
mySortedList = list(set(liste))
mySortedList.sort(key=len)
i = 0
while i<len(mySortedList)-1 :
    j = i+1
    while j < len(mySortedList):
        if mySortedList[j].startswith(mySortedList[i]):
            mySortedList.pop(j)
        else:
            j+=1
    i+=1
```

Comment: Your code doesn't run. Could you check it?

Comment: sorry about that, it runs now

Comment: Looks like the solution. let me doublecheck it and then update my post!

Comment: Your solution works but my listhas about 600 entries. When I am keeping the number of entries low it works. When I am including all entries I am getting an empty list. Now I have to look what the bug is :D thank you anyway. If you got an idea let me know...

Comment: Didn't know about `startswith`, thanks!

Comment: @soulwreckedyouth, is there an empty line in your list of 600?

Comment: This doesn't work for generla data if there are different types of strings of similar lentgh. No need to sort by length! Just sort lexicographically, and prefixes will always come right before strings containing them

Comment: Yeah fixed that! The list contained empty entries...

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by this sentence: If two strings start with two equal words, they are considered duplicates. You can change this number if you want.

```
list_ = ['I am googling for the solution for an hour now',
         'I am googling for the solution for an hour now --Sent via mail--',
         'I am googling for the solution for an hour now --Sent via mail-- What are you doing?',
         'Hello I am good thanks >> How are you?',
         'Hello I am good thanks',
         'Hello I am good thanks >>']

all_duplicates = {}

for string in list_:

    # like 'I am' or 'Hello I'
    first_two_words = ' '.join(string.split(maxsplit=2)[:2])

    if first_two_words in all_duplicates:

        v = all_duplicates[first_two_words]

        # check to see if this item of the list is considered duplicate
        if first_two_words in v:
            if len(string) < len(v):
                all_duplicates[first_two_words] = string
    else:
        all_duplicates[first_two_words] = string


for k, v in all_duplicates.items():
    print(f"{k} --> {v}")
```

output:

```
I am --> I am googling for the solution for an hour now
Hello I --> Hello I am good thanks
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fully working example. By sorting the list by string length, you can only get duplicate of a given string after the string in the list. This way the code runs faster.

My code returns the smallest substrings in the list. So if a string is contains inside another, it will eliminate the second string.

```py
str_list = [
    "I am googling for the solution for an hour now",
    "I am googling for the solution for an hour now --Sent via mail--",
    "I am googling for the solution for an hour now --Sent via mail-- What are you doing?",
    "Hello I am good thanks >> How are you?",
    "Hello I am good thanks",
    "Hello I am good thanks >>",
]

wrong_strings = []
str_list.sort(key=len)

for idx, item1 in enumerate(str_list):
    for item2 in str_list[idx + 1 :]:
        if item1 in item2:
            wrong_strings.append(item2)

base_strings = [string for string in str_list if string not in wrong_strings]

print(f"{base_strings=}")
```

This also work when a string has no duplicate in the list.

Answer (score 0):

I will implement something not really optimized, just to explain.

Looking at the input data, I assume you want not only one shortest sentence, but the set of shortest that are not similar.

Here the proposed implementation

```py
liste = ['I am googling for the solution for an hour now','I am googling for the solution for an hour now --Sent via mail--', 'I am googling for the solution for an hour now --Sent via mail-- What are you doing?', 'Hello I am good thanks >> How are you?','Hello I am good thanks', 'Hello I am good thanks >>']


# First you need some function to get the common part between two sentences
def common_part(sen1, sen2):
    min_length = min( len(sen1), len(sen2) )

    for i in range(min_length):
        if sen1[i] != sen2[i]:
            return sen1[:i]
    # if we exit for loop sentences are equal or
    # one is a substring of the other
    return sen1[:min_length]

# than you can implement some logic checking for common parts

# I create a set to contains elements that has the advantage
# to avoid repetition if you add the same element twice
small_sentences = set()

# than you compare each element with others
# this is not a good algorithm, Big O notation is O(2^n)

for f1 in liste:
    shortest = f1  # store the sentence and compare with all others
    for f2 in liste:
        common = common_part(f1, f2)
        # I define a minimum of 5 chars to be considered "similar"
        # Than if the common part is smaller we take it as good
        if len(common) > 5 and len(shortest) > len(common):
            shortest = common
    small_sentences.add(shortest)

print(small_sentences)
```